# Correct use of uncover

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{\textbf{Motivation}}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\uncover<1-3>{\item }
\uncover<2-3>{\begin{itemize}
\item Some Item
\item Some Item
\item Some Item
\end{itemize}}
\uncover<3-3>{\item some item}
\uncover<3-3>{\item some item}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\uncover<1-3>{\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{img/Img2.jpg}
\caption{\tiny URL}
\end{figure}}       
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\enddocument
```

Is there a better way to keep the features of `\pause`? If I use `\pause` the caption below the image in the second column is greyed out until the end. In order to have the caption not greyed out until the end I use the `\uncover` command.

However I now need to know beforehand how many times I want to uncover items in order to write the correct command i.e. `\uncover<1-3>`. I want all items to be visible until the end when I uncover them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative overlays may be a solution:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43,10pt]{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{\textbf{Motivation}}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\uncover<+->{\item }
\uncover<+->{\begin{itemize}
\item Some Item
\item Some Item
\item Some Item
\end{itemize}}
\uncover<+->{\item some item}
\uncover<+->{\item some item}
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{\tiny URL}
\end{figure} 
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```